# Matching data 3 columns on same row

Tags: excel, multiple-columns

I want to match the data in 2 columns so if the data appears in both column A and B then then data in B is placed on the same row

To make this slightly trickier i have data in column C that must follow column B

eg

```
column A         Column B          Column C
Test1            Test3              james
Test3            Test1              john
```

when i run the code i need the following results

```
column A         Column B          Column C
Test1            Test1              john
Test3            Test3              james
```

any help would be great

Regards

Simon

Answer (score 0):

It not beutiful, but it does the job. :)

Sub test()
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
Dim strTempB As String, strTempC As String

```
i = 4

Do While ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Ark1").Range("A" & i).Text <> ""
    j = 4
    Do While ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Ark1").Range("B" & j).Text <> ""

        If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Ark1").Range("A" & i).Text = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Ark1").Range("B" & j).Text Then
            strTempB = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Ark1").Range("B" & i).Text
            strTempC = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Ark1").Range("C" & i).Text


            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Ark1").Range("B" & i).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Ark1").Range("B" & j).Text
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Ark1").Range("C" & i).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Ark1").Range("C" & j).Text
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Ark1").Range("B" & j).Value = strTempB
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Ark1").Range("C" & j).Value = strTempC
        End If

        j = j + 1
    Loop
    i = i + 1
Loop
```

End Sub